# error unhandled exception during loading desiger for the first time in visual studio 2012

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8

I'm working on visual studio 2012, windows phone sdk 8.0, windows phone emulator 8.0,on windows 8.1 pro.

when I launched the visual studio and created a first project in windows phone app 
, after creating the project the designer is not shown. Its giving some exceptions in loading the designer.

> System.NullReferenceException Object reference not set to an instance
>   of an object.    at
>   Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.STAMarshaler.WaitForCompletion(NestedCallContext
>   nestedCallContext, BlockingCall call, WaitHandle timeoutSignal)    at
>   Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.STAMarshaler.MarshalOutSynchronous(Action
>   action, Int32 targetApartmentId, WaitHandle aborted, WaitHandle
>   timeoutSignal)    at
>   Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.STAMarshaler.MarshalOut(Action
>   action, Int32 targetApartmentId, WaitHandle aborted,
>   CallSynchronizationMode syncMode, WaitHandle timeoutSignal)    at
>   Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.ThreadMarshaler.MarshalOut[TValue](RemoteHandle1
>   targetObject, Action action, CallSynchronizationMode syncMode)    at
>   Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.ThreadMarshaler.MarshalOut[TResult,TValue](RemoteHandle1
>   targetObject, Func2 func, CallSynchronizationMode syncMode)    at
>   Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.LocalDesignerService.CreateDesignerImpl(IHostSourceItem
>   item, IHostTextEditor editor, RemoteCancellationToken
>   remoteCancelToken)    at
>   Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.LocalDesignerService.<>c__DisplayClass12.b__11(RemoteCancellationToken
>   remoteToken)    at
>   Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.LocalDesignerService.CallWithCancellation[TResult](CancellationToken
>   cancelToken, Func`2 func)    at
>   Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.LocalDesignerService.Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.IDesignerService.CreateDesigner(IHostSourceItem
>   item, IHostTextEditor editor, CancellationToken cancelToken)    at
>   Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.IsolatedDesignerService.IsolatedDesignerView.CreateDesignerViewInfo(CancellationToken
>   cancelToken)
>
> System.NullReferenceException Object reference not set to an instance
>   of an object.
>
> Server stack trace:     at
>   Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.STAMarshaler.WaitForCompletion(NestedCallContext
>   nestedCallContext, BlockingCall call, WaitHandle timeoutSignal)    at
>   Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.STAMarshaler.MarshalIn(Action
>   action, Int32 targetApartmentId)    at
>   Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.ThreadMarshaler.MarshalIn(IRemoteObject
>   targetObject, Action action)    at
>   Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.ThreadMarshaler.MarshalIn[TResult](IRemoteObject
>   targetObject, Func`1 func)    at
>   Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.RemoteDesignerService.Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.IRemoteDesignerService.CreateDesigner(IRemoteHostSourceItem
>   remoteItem, IRemoteHostTextEditor remoteEditor,
>   IRemoteCancellationToken remoteToken)    at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink._PrivateProcessMessage(IntPtr
>   md, Object[] args, Object server, Object[]& outArgs)    at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.SyncProcessMessage(IMessage
>   msg)
>
> Exception rethrown at [0]:     at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage
>   reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)    at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData&
>   msgData, Int32 type)    at
>   Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.IRemoteDesignerService.CreateDesigner(IRemoteHostSourceItem
>   remoteItem, IRemoteHostTextEditor remoteEditor,
>   IRemoteCancellationToken cancelToken)    at
>   Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.LocalDesignerService.<>c__DisplayClass8.b__6(IRemoteDesignerService
>   d)    at
>   Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.ThreadMarshaler.<>c__DisplayClass4`2.b__3()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.STAMarshaler.Call.InvokeWorker()
>
> System.NullReferenceException Object reference not set to an instance
>   of an object.    at
>   Microsoft.Expression.Platform.PlatformService.PlatformEntry.get_PlatformCreator()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Expression.Platform.PlatformService.GetPlatformCreator(String
>   frameworkSpec)    at
>   Microsoft.Expression.Platform.PlatformService.IsCompatibleFramework(FrameworkName
>   hostFramework, FrameworkName guestFramework)    at
>   Microsoft.Expression.DesignSurface.Project.ProjectContextManager.GetProjectContext(IHostProject
>   project, IPlatform platform, Boolean create)    at
>   Microsoft.Expression.DesignSurface.Project.ProjectContextManager.GetSourceItemContext(IHostSourceItem
>   sourceItem)    at
>   Microsoft.Expression.DesignSurface.DesignerService.CreateDesigner(IHostSourceItem
>   item, IHostTextEditor editor, CancellationToken cancelToken)    at
>   Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.RemoteDesignerService.<>c__DisplayClass10.<>c__DisplayClass12.b__f(CancellationToken
>   cancelToken)    at
>   Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.RemoteDesignerService.CallWithCancellation[TResult](IRemoteCancellationToken
>   remoteToken, Func2 func)    at
>   Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.RemoteDesignerService.<>c__DisplayClass10.b__e()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.ThreadMarshaler.<>c__DisplayClass16`1.b__15()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.STAMarshaler.Call.InvokeWorker()

Answer (score 0):

You get the same message if you have problem with the project (just remove the obj folder) or with the Visual Studio per se.

I recommend you to check if you have the Update 4 of the VS2012.

Also, also, remember to have a processor with virtualization enabled.